# Check that $(a - b)^{2} \leq K(a^{2} + b^{2})$ holds for $K=3$ and/or for some $K<3$

Tags: inequality

Is it true that for any real numbers $(a,b)$,

$$(a - b)^{2} \leq 3a^{2} + 3b^{2}\ ?$$

Also, if this is true, is there a way to sharpen this
bound to

$$(a - b)^{2} \leq K(a^{2} + b^{2})$$

for some $K < 3$?

Comment: Got something from an answer below?

Answer (score 3):

$$\color{red}{\mathbf 2}\cdot(a^2+b^2)-(a-b)^2=(a+b)^2\geqslant0$$

Answer (score 1):

$$0\le(a+b)^{2}=a^2+b^2+2ab \implies -2ab\le a^2+b^2,$$
$$(a-b)^{2}=a^2+b^2-2ab\le 2a^2+2b^2.$$

Answer (score 0):

$$Ka^2+Kb^2-(a-b)^2=(K-1)a^2+2ab+(K-1)b^2=(a+b)^2+(K-2)(a^2+b^2)\ge0$$
if $K\ge2$, else it's false by setting $b=-a\ne0$. So $K=2$ is the minimal bound.